# Pointer dereferencing in Rust

Tags: rust

I am rather confused about the following problem. If I understand it correctly

```
let x = &42;
```

is expanded internally to

```
let x_value = 42;
let x = &x;
```

I think I have seen this in the Rust book somewhere but I cannot find the reference to it.

My problem is concerning the following code:

```
let x = 42;
let rx = &x;
let px = rx as *const i32 as *mut i32;
unsafe {
  *px = 0;
}
println!("{}", x);
```

As expected this prints `0`. However, if I write

```
let rx = &42;
let px = rx as *const i32 as *mut i32;
unsafe {
  println!("Deref");
  *px = 0;
}
println!("{}", x);
```

the program terminates after printing out `Deref`. Aparently something goes wrong when `px` gets dereferenced. I guess my first assessment about `let x = &42` getting expanded internally is wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're invoking undefined behavior. From the [Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#behavior-considered-undefined):

> ### 12.3 Behavior considered undefined
>
> The following is a list of behavior which is forbidden in all Rust code, including within unsafe blocks and unsafe functions. [...]
>
> - Mutating non-mutable data (that is, data reached through a shared reference or data owned by a `let` binding), unless that data is contained within an `UnsafeCell<U>`.

Since you're mutating non-mutable data, you're invoking undefined behavior. The fact that it works at all in the first version is just (bad) luck.

Comment: I looked up the implementation of `UnsafeCell<T>` and wanted to experiment with raw pointers. The important part I overlooked is the attribute `#[lang = "unsafe_cell"]`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
let x = 42;
let rx = &x;
```

Here you create a new variable on stack and write the value 42 that comes from the code of your program.
When creating a reference, it is referencing this value on stack.
When you change the value by *px = 0; you gain access to the value on stack and can change it.

In the second case

```
let rx = &42;
```

you create a reference directly to the value stored in the part of memory that stores the code (instructions and other data). And this part of memory is immutable.